# SSIS: Best way to split text?

Tags: ssis

What would be the best way to split a text column such as this:-

```
id  | Name               |
--------------------------
 1  | John Doe (Q849yu)  |
 2  | Fred Blogs (f564ju |
```

To this:-

```
id  | Name       | PersonalID
--------------------------
 1  | John Doe   | (Q849yu)
 2  | Fred Blogs | (f564ju
```

I have tried to do this in Derived Column, however I can't seem to get the expression right.

Is there an easier way than derived column?

Comment: Got to ask. Why is your data stored this way in the first place?

Comment: I wouldn't store data in that way (i just use that as a example), but when i import from a csv it comes like that.

Comment: you should probably punch whoever gives you that file directly in the face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick. Assuming, that searched string is always after last space character:

```
ltrim(RIGHT( RTRIM( "John Doe (Q849yu) "), FINDSTRING( REVERSE( RTRIM( "John Doe (Q849yu) "))," ",1)))
```

If you want a better way to do this, especially for more complicated strings, try using Regular Expressions in `Script Component`. Once you write a component, writing a regex and modifying it is a piece of cake in comparison to messy expressions in Derived Column transformation.

You'll learn more here:
[Pattern matching in SSIS using Regular Expressions and the Script component](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/07/pattern-matching-in-ssis-using-regular-expressions-and-the-script-component/)

Answer (score 1):

A substring / findstring expression would be the best solution in this case. 
Search for " (" with a findstring. Then use that number in a substring expression. Something like this for the first part: SUBSTRING([Name], 1, FINDSTRING([Name], " (", 1))

In SSIS 2012 the TOKEN was introduced. Which could be useful if you have a [multi-value](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/10/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html) column. Last alternative is the Script Component with a .net string split method.